# Using regular expressions in python raw input

Tags: python, regex, aho-corasick

I am trying to create a script that will allow a user to enter a number of regular expressions which will pass through an input file and retrieve matches. I am currently using ahocorasick but am getting issues when I try and enter regexed patterns.

I enter a regex into the second raw_input (colour_regex) but receive this error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PLA_Enrichment_options.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
  File "PLA_Enrichment_options.py", line 41, in main
    tree.add(regex)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ahocorasick/__init__.py", line 29, in add

TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not _sre.SRE_Pattern

file_name = raw_input("What is the filename you wish to enhance? ")
enhanced_name = file_name.replace(".csv", "")

# User regexed input
tree = ahocorasick.KeywordTree()
print ("What regex would you like to use for colour? (Enter 'exit' to move on) ")
colour_regex = raw_input()
regex = re.compile(colour_regex)
while colour_regex != "exit":
    tree.add(regex)
tree.make()

print 'Finding colour matches...'
output = open(enhanced_name + '-colour.csv', 'w')
file = open(feed_name, 'r')
for line in iter(file):
    id, title, desc, link, image = line.strip('\n').split('\t')
    offerString = '|'.join([title.lower(), desc.lower(), link.lower()])
    keywords = set()
    for match in tree.findall_long(offerString): # find colours
        indices = list(match)
        keyword = offerString[indices[0]:indices[1]]
        if re.search(r'(?<![Ã¢ÃªÃ®Ã´Ã»Ã¤Ã«Ã¯Ã¶Ã¼Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº])\b%s\b(?![Ã¢ÃªÃ®Ã´Ã»Ã¤Ã«Ã¯Ã¶Ã¼Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº])' %(keyword), offerString):
            keywords.add(keyword)                                     
    if keywords:
        output.write('\t'.join([id, '|'.join(keywords), desc, link, image])+'\n')
    else:
        output.write('\t'.join([id, title, desc, link, image])+'\n')
file.close()
output.close()
```

Any help/guidance to the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What issues are you having with this program? Where does it happen?

Comment: When I enter a regex when first prompted for a colour, I receive this error:

TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not _sre.SRE_Pattern

Comment: Please add the full error message (with line number) to the question.

Comment: What is the filename you wish to enrich? plf-output-290834.csv

What regex would you like to use for colour? (Enter 'exit' to move on) 
moule(.*?)pierre

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Enhancement_options.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
  File "PLA_Enrichment_options.py", line 41, in main
    tree.add(regex)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ahocorasick/__init__.py", line 29, in add
    
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not _sre.SRE_Pattern

Comment: The above relates to the raw_input located in the line: regex = re.compile(colour_regex)

Comment: You can edit the original question. Line breaks in code blocks are not visible in comments. It's much easier to read when formatted, and is also needed to understand the question.

Comment: What's with the funky WTF-8 mojibake in the `re.search` argument?  I guess that's supposed to be `r'(?<![âêîôûäëïöüàèìòùáéíóú])\b%s\b(?![âêîôûäëïöüàèìòùáéíóú])'`?  But what's the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1):

```
tree = ahocorasick.KeywordTree()
regex = re.compile(colour_regex)
tree.add(regex)
```

You have passed the wrong type to ahocorasick.KeywordTree.add()

`regex` is a compiled regular expression object. The type is `_sre.SRE_Pattern`. If you use the original string instead, you will not get this error.

```
tree.add(colour_regex)
```

Also, this will cause an infinite loop. I think you want `if` instead of `while`, or put `colour_regex = raw_input()` inside the loop.

```
while colour_regex != "exit":
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have fixed the infinite loop. I no longer receive the error above and the script runs to completion. However, the regexes I enter do not seem to act like regexes as I do not receive the expected output. For example in the file I am running the script through I have 'red flowery dress', so if I enter the regex red(.*)dress, I want to receive back all matches to that regex.

Comment: Don't know. Try to isolate the problematic code in a function so that you can  test it in isolation. If you still can't find the bug, you should post it as a new question.